# How to serialize LocalDateTime with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, java-time

I got the following piece of code:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    String now = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new SomeClass(LocalDateTime.now()));
    System.out.println(now);
```

And I get this:

> {"time":{"hour":20,"minute":49,"second":42,"nano":99000000,"dayOfYear":19,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","month":"JANUARY","dayOfMonth":19,"year":2017,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}

What I want to achieve is a string in ISO8601

> 2017-01-19T18:36:51Z

Comment: Would something like this work: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"); and then: 
        mapper.setDateFormat(df);

Comment: My situation is the reverse way, What | want to get is your output and what I am getting is what you are looking for. I have the exact same configuration as you. Any help?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is probably due to mistake in your code. You were using new unconfigured instance of mapper, here is the fix:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
 mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
 String now = mapper.writeValueAsString(new SomeClass(LocalDateTime.now()));
 System.out.println(now);
```

Answer (score 8):

I use `SimpleModule` and the best practice for me is to have my own registered implementation for serialization and deserialization:

```
final SimpleModule localDateTimeSerialization = new SimpleModule();
    localDateTimeSerialization.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());
    localDateTimeSerialization.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());

objectMapper.registerModule(localDateTimeSerialization);
```

Serializer:

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

  private final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

  @Override
  public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeString(value.format(format));
  }
  
}
```

And deserialization:

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

  private final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(p.getValueAsString(), fmt);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This answer is great as JavaTimeModule will not do the job in any case. For example, when you need the serialisation of a datetime pattern using multiple possible fraction digit formats `[.SSS][.SS][.S]`. JavaTimeModule would out of the box create `.123.12.1`. Having a custom implementation is a) great for visibility and b) pretty much straightforward. thx @jnemecz

Answer (score 5):

This is what you can do for `OffsetDateTime`:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX")
private OffsetDateTime timeOfBirth;
```

For LocalDateTime you cannot use XXXX (zone offset) because there is no offset information. So you can drop it. But [ISO8601 discourages using Local Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as it's ambiguous:

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation,
>   the time is assumed to be in local time. While it may be safe to
>   assume local time when communicating in the same time zone, it is
>   ambiguous when used in communicating across different time zones. Even
>   within a single geographic time zone, some local times will be
>   ambiguous if the region observes daylight saving time. It is usually
>   **preferable to indicate a time zone** (zone designator) using the
>   standard's notation.